# Unable to mutate Javascript Array inside a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I am facing a strange problem in my javascript code, I have function that returns a promise that contains all the tasks. Each task has a property project and this property contains an integer. Now, I want to fetch project by calling another function that also returns a promise so that I can convert the project property to a `Project` object. But when I try to that I get this error

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

Here is my code

```js
const allByProject = async (project: Project) : Promise<Task[]> => {
    const  allTasks = await TaskStore.allByProject(project);
    allTasks.forEach(async (task: Task, i) => {
        // In this case tasks return contains a project id instead of the project object
        let projecId: any = task.project;
        const project = await ProjectService.getById(projecId);
        allTasks[i].project = project;  // THIS GENERATES the ERROR.
    });
    console.log('All tasks: ', allTasks);
    return allTasks;
}
```

Comment: There is an error in the promise function that needs to handle. Try to add `.catch` to handle errors

Comment: Apparently, `allTasks[i].project` is a readonly property. :) As we have no idea what `TaskStore.allByProject` does, it is impossible to say how to resolve this, except "don't assign values to readonly properties".

Comment: Then what's the alternative here, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Copy the entire object with a new project value

Comment: @Yimin I tried that but I think it still needs wait for this to be resolved `await ProjectService.getById(projecId);`

Comment: Yeah, wait for that, and then do allTasks[i] = {...allTasks[i], project: project}

Comment: The suggested question does not modify a global array inside a promise, how is that question related?